# Convert NSString date to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there an effective way of converting from this type of NSString data to an NSDate:

> 2011-05-07+02:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NSDateFromatter class for this.
Set the format of your date, then use

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

method.
See [NSDateFormatter reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Much better alternative is using [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can specify string format, locale, timezone.

```
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *en_US = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:en_US];
[en_US release];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-60*60*7]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[ NSDate dateWithString: myStr ];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Simply read the documentation... There is such a method... : S

Answer (score 0):

See dateWithString:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Regards
Friedrich

Comment: There is no such method in iOS

Answer (score 0):

As ssteinberg said, and the format is as following.

```
// 2011-05-07+02:00
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd+hh:mm:"];
```