# How can I convert string into date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two strings:
date1 = 3-5-2014;
date2 = 4-2-2010;

I have to convert them in date and then compare them. I want the same format of date as in strings i.e., dd-mm-yyyy. How it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *string=@"03-05-2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

enjoy...

Comment: This code will result in 2 memory leaks. `dateFormatter` must be released and there is no need to allocate an `NSDate` to `dateFromString`—`dateFromString:` returns an autoreleased instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract `NSDate` objects from strings using the `NSDateFormatter` class. See the [Date Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) section Apple's Data Formatting Guide for a detailed explanation and sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat release];
```

here is the SO post

[Convert NSString date to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485112/convert-nsstring-date-to-nsdate)

Comment: I don't want this fomat. please see the format in my question.

Comment: use the below statement and plz let me know if you still require help [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"25-8-2010"];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
    [dateFormatter release];
```

Hope this works for you 
Cheers :)